# Error when presenting different storyboard programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have an app with 2 Storyboards. One of them is the main app stuff, and another one is a setup storyboard to set up a user profile. Right now, I have it set up so the main interface is the `Setup.storyboard`. In the first view controller in that storyboard, in the  `-viewWillAppear:animated` method, it checks a `NSUserDefault` to see if the setup is complete. If it is, I execute this code.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"userHasCompletedSetup"]) {

        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        SWRevealViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"initialVC"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

I get the error `Warning: Attempt to present <SWRevealViewController: 0x7ff20a595220> on <MPOSetupOneViewController: 0x7ff20a720b80> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

(I am using `SWRevealViewController` in my app for a menu.)

I get this error, and the view controller does not switch. Is there any way I can switch storyboards based on a `NSUserDefault`? Could I maybe do this in the AppDelegate?

Comment: @matt How did that work? Will -> Did just made a crucial part of my app work correctly. If you can add that into an answer ill accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the code to `viewDidAppear:`. In `viewWillAppear:`, your view is not in the interface yet (that is what "will" means), so there is nothing to present from.